# How to Select Column With Max Value In T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find the month with the most sales, I've been able display every month with its sales using:

```
SELECT Month(orderdate)  AS Month, 
       Year(orderdate)   AS Year, 
       Sum(salesorderid) AS Sales 
FROM   sales.salesorderheader 
GROUP  BY Month(orderdate), 
          Year(orderdate)
```

Which shows

[image: This Result]

But I just want to select the top sales month.

Comment: `select top 1 ... order by Sum(salesorderid)`

Comment: use `row_number()`

Comment: No order by clause -> no defined order of rows. Don't assume just because you see things as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm correct, you want to print single result with the max sales
 And here "salesorderid" is the total sales of that month

- Try adding MAX

```
SELECT Month(orderdate)  AS Month, 
       Year(orderdate)   AS Year, 
       MAX(Sum(salesorderid)) AS Sales 
FROM   sales.salesorderheader 
GROUP  BY Month(orderdate), 
          Year(orderdate)
```

- Or try using HAVING clause

```
SELECT Month(orderdate)  AS Month, 
       Year(orderdate)   AS Year, 
       Sum(salesorderid) AS Sales 
FROM   sales.salesorderheader 
GROUP  BY Month(orderdate), 
          Year(orderdate) 
HAVING MAX(Sum(salesorderid))
```

since Sum(salesorderid) is the total sales this might work...

Answer (score 1):

You have to `group` it first by `year` then `month`. Then use `count()` not `sum()` (seems your column is SalesOrderID), but if you are trying to get the `sum of sales` it should be something like `sum(salesamount)`. 
Also change your `column aliases`, those are `sql keywords`.

```
select month(OrderDate) as oMonth, year(OrderDate) as oYear
    , count(1) as SalesCount
from SalesOrderHeader
group by year(OrderDate), month(OrderDate)
```

getting the `most number of sales`.

```
select top 1 * from (
    select month(OrderDate) as oMonth, year(OrderDate) as oYear
        , count(1) as SalesCount
    from SalesOrderHeader
    group by year(OrderDate), month(OrderDate)) t1
order by t1.SalesCount desc
```

Comment: ah yeah thank you that worked perfectly, sorry for the inconvenience but is there a way to do it without using TOP X, the specifications say that the incorrect use of this will result in loss of marks.

Comment: Define "incorrect use" - if you want a single row this is a common way to do it.

Comment: It doesn't say aha, Im sure this will be fine. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Just use `top (1)`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) Month(orderdate)  AS Month, 
       Year(orderdate)   AS Year, 
       Sum(salesorderid) AS Sales 
FROM sales.salesorderheader 
GROUP BY Month(orderdate), Year(orderdate) 
ORDER BY Sales DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1. Using `ORDER BY` "**field name**" `DESC`
2. If field "**salesorderid**" not in type number, `ORDER BY` function can't run. So you can change before, use `CAST("field name" AS Decimal)`

Check Below code snippet

```
SELECT Month(a.orderdate)  AS Month, 
       Year(a.orderdate)   AS Year, 
       Sum(a.salesorderid) AS Sales                                               
FROM   sales.salesorderheader  a
GROUP BY Month(a.orderdate),Year(a.orderdate) 
ORDER BY CAST(a.Sum(a.salesorderid), AS Decimal) DESC
```